# Validating XML using Notepad++ and XMLTools Plugin

Tags: xml, validation, notepad++, dtd

I'm learning XML and just started with a simple xml-file and external DTD I made myself. In order to validate I use Notepad++ and XMLTools Plugin. (Does anyone know if this works well according to the standards or has a better free alternative for me?)

This one is my external dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT auto (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST auto fahrgestellnummer CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT autohaus (auto | #PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST autohaus id CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Everything worked fine until I tried to allow the occurence of `auto` and/or `#PCDATA` for element `autohaus` in the DTD. I get the following error:

> Unable to load the dtd externalDTD.dtd.

If I erase "`| #PCDATA`" in line 3, there is no problem. Also using `,` instead of `|` does not work.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<!ELEMENT autohaus (auto | #PCDATA)>` is not legal in a DTD.

If you want to declare mixed content, allowing character data optionally interspersed with other elements (in any order), you must put the `#PCDATA` keyword first in the content model and use a "star" occurrence indicator. Like this:

```
<!ELEMENT autohaus (#PCDATA | auto)*>
```

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content